# Finding number of children of an element returns 'null' error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the number of children of a node by pure 'javascript' but getting unexpected error.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var a = document.getElementById('div1').children.length;
console.log(a);
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<div id="div1">
<p>This is para1.</p>
<p>This is para2.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

ERROR:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null
```

But, I can clearly see that my div has 2 children nodes. Can someone help?

Comment: Just put your `script` within `body` section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put your code to `onload` event

```
window.onload = function () {
    var a = document.getElementById('div1').children.length;
    console.log(a);
}
```

or put your script before `</body>`, because you are trying get DOM node before it will be created

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by the order of events during the page construction in your browser.

An HTML is parsed and evaluated synchronously, in order. Scripts are evaluated as soon as the occur in the HTML. When your script (`document.getElementById('div1')`...) is evaluated, the *div1* doesn't exist yet (it wasn't seen by the parser yet), and so the result is `null` and you get the exception.

That's why it's recommended to put inline script tags in the end of the HTML document, immediately before the body closing tag (`</body>`).